# How to custom serialize this Test class get output as flat structure (unwrapped XYZ class) using java

Tags: java, json, spring

[image]

As in the image I want to serialize the Test class to json using java

Comment: Can you elaborate more please ? What customisation you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method in the class Test that returns a string formatted like a JSON object.